# Footable sortable - checkboxes

Tags: sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, footable

is it possible to sort columns in the Footable which contain checkboxes, so that the checked checkboxes come to the top of the table or to the bottom?
Thank you

Comment: if i set data-value 0 or 1 to each <td> element it works on page load, but if I change any checkbox it isnt included in the sorting until I reload again

Comment: I've overcome this issue by adding and filtering an invisible field. Good luck.